# Switch dictionary in Python not converting int and str correctly

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

Followed on from a previous question, I've written a switch dictionary to replace switch statements in functions. I've placed this dictionary under def f(x) after receiving user input, like so. Then the function should write whatever was matched in the dictionary to 'a' and 'b', so it can be used in the add() function.

```
while loop == 1:
choice = menu()
if choice == '1':
    a = str(input("Enter a note: "))
    b = str(input("Enter an interval: "))

    def f(x):
        notes = {
            'C': 0,
            'Cs': 1,
            'D': 2,
            'Ds': 3,
            'E': 4,
            'F':5,
            'Fs': 6,
            'G': 7,
            'Gs': 8,
            'A': 9,
            'As': 10,
            'B': 11,
            }
        return = notes[x]


    def g(x):
        intervals = {
            'm2': 1,
            'mj2': 2,
            'm3': 3,
            'mj3': 4,
            'p4': 5,
            'T': 6,
            'p5': 7,
            'm6': 8,
            'mj6': 9,
            'm7': 10,
            'mj7': 11,
            }
        return intervals[x]

    f (a)
    g (b)
    add(a, b)
```

However I am getting a 'Not all arguments converted during string formatting' error at these two lines:

```
add(a, b)
```

and at the beginning of my script where I define the add function.

```
def add(a,b):
print ((a), "+", (b), "=", (a + b) %12)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this problem, as I don't really understand how the code is converting strings. Are my functions expecting integers and instead receiving strings?

Thank you!

Comment: Use should rename your variable too many 'a' and 'b' , give them context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
def add(va,vb):
    print ((va), "+", (vb), "=", (va + vb) %12)

aa =  f(a)
bb =  g(b)
add(aa, bb)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked. So my error was that I had too many variables called a and b, and they were overwriting each other?

Answer (score 0):

Try printing a and b before calling the add function to see what their values are.

My guess is, the variables inside the switch functions are inside the scope of the function and are not changing the variables outside the function.

Why don't you receive the returned values in a variable?

> a = f(a)
>
> b = g(b)

Comment: Printing a and b gives me the user input as a letter (C = C), so the function isn't writing the user input as integers correctly (i.e. C = 0). Could you explain how I can received the returned values in a variable? I don't quite understand.